# API doesn't return photos of group posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When querying posts from a group the photos are not returned most of the time even though the posts have photos.
We have a working app that uses those photos and starting from about 24 hours ago we almost don't get any photos.

For example, the following post - 45245752193_10152313354342194 
 has photos and it's also public, but the api doesn't return the photos:

This is my query:

```
45245752193_10152313354342194?fields=attachments,full_picture,picture
```

Full_picture and picture don't exists in the response, and in the attachment I get this:

```
  "description": "This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you.", 
            "title": "Attachment Unavailable", 
            "type": "unavailable"
```

I also tried to get the photos in two different ways and it didn't work.

1.Querying {group_id}/feed?fields=attachments,full_picture,picture,object_id,from
I get the same error string as before in the attachment field, picture and full_picture are empty.

2.Using fql with the following query:

```
SELECT source_id,attachment,post_id, message, like_info,comment_info,created_time, share_count,actor_id FROM stream  WHERE source_id in (45245752193) and
```

Here the attachments field is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the developer bug centre this is a valid bug, and Facebook are looking to fix this issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/752853894779368/